# Volley's onResponse() is not called (code was running correctly but sometimes it doesn't work)

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I already tested below code correctly at home without error.
But this same code doesn't work (especially around volley, db connection parts) at the office

The main issue is "onResponse() is not called"

-- What is the problem for this case?
-- How can I see the log or information related to this issue?

// ============================================================
Java code file

```
package com.example.mpandroidcharttest;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

...

// ============================================================
public class BarChartPosNegActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    // ============================================================
    BarChart barChart;
    ImageView iv_normal, iv_abnormal;

    public static String user_ID_passed_one = "";

    // ============================================================
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        // ============================================================
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // ============================================================
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bar_chart_pos_neg);

        // ============================================================
        barChart = findViewById(R.id.mp_BarChart);
        ...

        // ============================================================
        String passed_user_ID = "first_ID";
        BarChartPosNegActivity.user_ID_passed_one = passed_user_ID;

        // ============================================================
        get_refDB_up_down_numerical_table();
    }

    // ============================================================
    private ArrayList<BarEntry> dataValues1()
    {
        ArrayList<BarEntry> dataVals = new ArrayList<>();
        dataVals.add(new BarEntry(0f, 1000));
        dataVals.add(new BarEntry(1f, 25));
        return dataVals;
    }

    // ============================================================
    void chart_algorithm(JSONArray jsonArray_data)
    {
        // c local_urine_protein_criterion: urine protein criterion in local scope
        HashMap<String, String> local_urine_protein_criterion = new HashMap<>();

        // ============================================================
        try {
            // c ref_data: get ref data source (0th record)
            JSONObject ref_data_source = jsonArray_data.getJSONObject(0);

            // ============================================================
            // c hashmap_ref_data: ref data (JSONObject -> hashmap)
            HashMap<String, String> hashmap_ref_data = new HashMap<>();

            JSONArray keys = ref_data_source.names();
            for (int i = 0; i < keys.length(); ++i) 
            {
                String key = keys.getString(i); // Here's your key
                String value = ref_data_source.getString(key); // Here's your value

                if (key.substring(0, 5).equals("ref__")) 
                {
                    hashmap_ref_data.put(key, value);
                }
            }
            ...
        } 
        catch (JSONException e) 
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        // ============================================================
        BarDataSet barDataSet1 = new BarDataSet(dataValues1(), "DataSet 1");

        // ...

        // ============================================================
        // Pass barData to barChart
        barChart.setData(barData);

        barChart.invalidate();

        // ============================================================
        // ============================================================
        int urine_protein = 1;

        if (urine_protein == 1) 
        {
            iv_normal.setImageResource(R.drawable.posneg_neg_gray);
            iv_abnormal.setImageResource(R.drawable.posneg_pos_red);
        } 
        else if (urine_protein == 0) 
        {
            iv_normal.setImageResource(R.drawable.posneg_neg_green);
            iv_abnormal.setImageResource(R.drawable.posneg_pos_gray);
        }
    }

    // ============================================================
    void get_refDB_up_down_numerical_table()
    {
        Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response)
            {
                System.out.println("response response response response response response response response response response response ");
                System.out.println(response);

                try 
                {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                    System.out.println(jsonArray);
                    chart_algorithm(jsonArray);

                } 
                catch (JSONException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        RefDBNumericRequest loginRequest = new RefDBNumericRequest(responseListener);
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(BarChartPosNegActivity.this);
        queue.add(loginRequest);
    }
}
```

// ============================================================
Request java code file

```
package com.example.mpandroidcharttest;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import org.json.JSONArray;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

class RefDBNumericRequest extends StringRequest
{
    final static private String med_data_TBL = "http://example.com/med_data_and_ref_data_joined_TBL.php";
    private Map<String, String> map;

    // ============================================================
    // Constructor
    public RefDBNumericRequest(Response.Listener<String> listener)
    {
        // ============================================================
        super(Method.POST, med_data_TBL, listener, null);

        // ============================================================
        map = new HashMap<>();

        String userID = "first_ID";
        map.put("userID", userID);
    }

    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError
    {
        return map;
    }
}
```

// ============================================================
PHP file

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_id", "db_pass", "db_name");

    mysqli_query($con,'SET NAMES utf8');

    $userID = $_POST["userID"];

    // ============================================================
    $query = "SELECT * from med_data_TBL left join ref_db_TBL on med_data_TBL.user__recordID=ref_db_TBL.ref__DB_recordID";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    $json = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($json);

    mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

// ============================================================
Returned value in onResponse()

```
[{"user__recordID":"1","user__userID":"first_ID","user__urine_protein__posneg":"positive","user__glucose__down_up_numerical":"80","user__systolic_blood_pressure__down_up_numerical":"140","ref__DB_recordID":"1","ref__urine_protein__posneg":"negative","ref__glucose__down_up_numerical_down":"60","ref__glucose__down_up_numerical_up":"120","ref__systolic_blood_pressure__down_up_numerical_down":"60","ref__systolic_blood_pressure__down_up_numerical_up":"140"},
 {"user__recordID":"2","user__userID":"second_ID","user__urine_protein__posneg":"negative","user__glucose__down_up_numerical":"130","user__systolic_blood_pressure__down_up_numerical":"50","ref__DB_recordID":null,"ref__urine_protein__posneg":null,"ref__glucose__down_up_numerical_down":null,"ref__glucose__down_up_numerical_up":null,"ref__systolic_blood_pressure__down_up_numerical_down":null,"ref__systolic_blood_pressure__down_up_numerical_up":null},
 {"user__recordID":"3","user__userID":"third_ID","user__urine_protein__posneg":"positive","user__glucose__down_up_numerical":"50","user__systolic_blood_pressure__down_up_numerical":"120","ref__DB_recordID":null,"ref__urine_protein__posneg":null,"ref__glucose__down_up_numerical_down":null,"ref__glucose__down_up_numerical_up":null,"ref__systolic_blood_pressure__down_up_numerical_down":null,"ref__systolic_blood_pressure__down_up_numerical_up":null}]
```

// ============================================================
Edit
At the office, I ran into following message (same package but a different signature, when I run the same code in 2 different places like home and office) again.
[image]

And I clicked "Ok", now volley's onResponse() can be called.
If someone knows why this message shows up and how to prevent this issue if the issue is actually related to this message, please guide me.
/mnt/external_disk/Capture_temp/2019_09_03_09:04:16.png

Comment: Post you logcat here.

Comment: @AmrishKakadiya Okay I'll try it next day.

Answer (score -1):

After I got to home, I ran the same code again (which didn't run at the office)

It runs fine. And I saw following message as a clue for this issue:

```
Application Installation Failed

The device already has an application with the same package but a different signature.
In order to proceed, you will have to uninstall the existing application
WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!
Do you want to uninstall the existing application?
```

Comment: @AmrishKakadiya Well. I don't know why that message shows (when I run the same code on the different places) and I don't know why the same code doesn't run on the one place and the code can run on the another place. About the message of "Do you want to uninstall the existing application", that is just what I saw when I run the code, guessing one clue about this issue, to let others to know it.

Comment: **The device already has an application with the same package but a different signature.** you have to uninstall previous app because new app have different signature.